# for statement in python not working

Tags: python, nonetype

trying to make a simple program that takes the word "supercalifragilisticexpialidocious" and displays it with the consonants replaced with a dash. This is the code:

```
message = print("supercalifragilisticexpialidocious")

result_str = ""

CONSONANTS = "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVXZWY"

print()

for letter in message:
    if letter not in CONSONANTS:
         result_str += letter

    else:
         result_str += "-"

print(result_str)

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit:")
```

When I run it in the module, it prints `"message"` correctly but gives this error instead of printing `"result_str"`:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/CSC119/final exam program 4.py", line 13, in <module>
    for letter in message:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

So what is my problem??
Thank you.

Comment: you cant assign a variable to a print statement. just keep it `message = 'super...'`

Answer (score 2):

```
message = "supercalifragilisticexpialidocious"
```

not print?

Comment: I changed that, and now the output is just:            `supercalifragilisticexpialidocious                            supercalifragilisticexpialidocious`

Comment: No dashes in for consonants

Comment: Your consonants are all in CAPS so wont match the lowercase chars you're comparing them too?

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign a print statement to a variable. You need to do `message = text` not `message = print(text)`

Comment: I changed that, and now the output is just: `supercalifragilisticexpialidocious supercalifragilisticexpialidocious` instead of the second one having dashes instead of consonants

Comment: i figured it out, needed to have the lowercase consonants added because it was only looking for uppercase to replace with dashes. works now. thank you!

Comment: No problem glad you found the answer. I didn't have the chance to try it as I was working on a question of my own.